# Causal inference - difference between blocking a backdoor path and adding a variable to regression

Tags: regression, causality, causal-diagram

I have just started this [introductory course to causal inference](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crash-course-in-causality). The DAG approach is completely new to me even though I come from an econometric background (though that dates back to 15 years ago).

The discussion around confounders reminds me of the [endogeneity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)) in econometrics, especially when confounders are unmeasured (e.g. [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias)). In this case, I remember [instrumental variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation) to be a workaround strategy, and explaining IV with DAGs makes a lot more sense!

However, the prefered strategy with DAGs seems to be blocking backdoor paths by conditioning on confounders (which will allow the ignorability assumption $(Y^{0}, Y^{1} \perp A|X)$ to be valid). **I am wondering how blocking a path from a confounder is actually different from including those confounder in the regression?**

For simplicity, suppose we have this DAG :

[image]

I would believe that if $X$ (the confounder) is measured in addition to $A$ (the treatment), then regressing $Y$ (the outcome) on both variables would lead to correct estimates (supposing we are using the correct regression function).

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You're not wrong. Including $X$ in the regression is typically *how* you condition on a variable in the regression setting. There are other ways to condition (stratify, backdoor adjustment, frontdoor adjustment, and instrumental variables).

Comment: Just want to add that propensity score methods do this too!

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb indicating which method is superior to another (or maybe given enough context)? I have recently encountered this statement suggesting to ban matching: "Much has been written about [propensity matching and] why it’s terrible and how it will lead to wrong estimates. If you can compute propensity scores, you can use inverse propensity weighting instead." (see https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-a-b-testing-primer-on-causal-inference-d8e462d90a0b).